# Python subprocess call fails when string with comma is passed as argument

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I'm on Windows and having a subprocess call like below to a batch script as below:

```
        print(curValue)
        subprocess.call([BA_EDITING_SCRIPT,
            self.blazeInstallationFolder,
            self.repoFolder,
            curMetaphor,
            self.romProjectPath,
            curInstPath,
            curMetaphorType,
            curRule,
            curType,
            curValue])
```

In my batch script, I print curValue argument which is passed as the 9th argument by

```
echo ****** BA Editing JAR Calling Batch Script: initiated ******
echo %9
```

This is the combined output I'm getting:

```
{'ctr':0,'__meta_klass':'CodeBuilderViewModel'}
****** BA Editing JAR Calling Batch Script: initiated ******
{'ctr':0
```

Looks like the string is broken by the commas while it's being passed by subprocess call. Any ideas to fix this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Command-line arguments are expected to be single values, such as strings and integers.  But you're passing a dictionary as a command-line argument, which won't work.

Comment: Argument passing is robust in Linux or Unix, because the underlying system call used to start a new command knows natively about distinct arguments. But on Windows, the system call passes a whole command line and the child process has to separate the parameters on spaces. That means that as soon of one of the parameters can contain spaces bad things are to be expected... You should try to see whether the remaining parts of the strings occur in the following parameters and then try to concatenate them back.

Comment: Add the operating system for clarity. And consider a working example where you pass a hard-coded value to a simple script that just prints out its parameters. Note that it isn't clear what the type of `curValue` is. It looks like a dict, but that wouldn't work in a call to a subprocess.

Comment: That looks like a dictionary but it is a string object in Python. So I would expect it to be treated as a string. Also I'm on Windows.